# How to access a networked domain from Windows 7 on VirtualBox?

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox

I am trying to set up Windows 7 on Virtual Box. There is one little oddity - I'm using an ISO image which we get given by our IT department to set up new PCs, so I don't have a local machine admin id and can only login to my domain user name. And the trouble is, I seem to have a networking problem reaching the domain.

I have set up VirtualBox successfully. I have created an Ubuntu VM using default parameters and it works, and can access the Internet (once I had configured the proxy), so I conclude that VirtualBox basically works.

I then set up a W7 VM, and everything goes ok until I get to the login. Here the login screen gives me a message "problem accessing server" and it is impossible to login to my domain.

I have tried changing the networking from NAT to Bridged Networking, but it makes no difference.

Comment: Have you talked to your IT department and explained the problem to them?

Comment: I have (it's a big organisation). I'm still trying to understand how the setup of domains works, but at least they have given me a local admin password for the machine, so I have successfully logged in and successfully accessed both the Internet and a shared folder, so in principle there isn't a particular problem with the networking.